Best method to pull in depositors and amounts of a Safe to be used in a Module?
Been designing a protocol fee Module, which we need to keep track of all deposits into a Safe (addresses and amounts) in which if a refund happens, there is no fee enforcement. Thus the module needs to runs some logic on withdraws to determine if a fee is applied. What is the best way to do this?

Dallascat,
Thanks for this question.
First of all, the Safe Transaction Service supports many tokens. You can query the tokens via the API (you find the token section at the bottom) or the Api Kit. For these tokens, our API returns the balances of the Safe.
But you want to track the individual deposits. The Safe{Core} SDK does not offer a way to listen to deposit events. So you would have to set up event listeners with viem or something similar.
If you want to implement this with Solidity, use your smart contract to facilitate the deposits and apply your own internal logic.
I hope this answer can guide you in the right direction for your use case. Please mark this question as answered or leave me a comment.

I'll look into viem, since we do use that in our FE, we just can't use the SDK. As far as deposits, I assume writing a function in our Module to facilitate deposits into the Safe? I can incorporate that, just want to make sure when you say the smart contract, it is our modules we are building all this logic into. Thanks for all your help!!

Yes exactly. You must listen to your own smart contract if you implement the deposit function (or however you call it) yourself. If you send the token to Safe directly, you will have to listen to the events of the ERC20 contract.
